# Looking for a Gata Kamsky quote - 'you must be playing a different kind of chess'

Tags: grandmaster

I remember a really interesting moment from the coverage of one of the past US chess championships (probably 2015 or before). Kamsky had just finished his game and was asked by Maurice Ashley for his opinion on one of the games in progress. So Maurice starts with how White has all this advantages, more space... certain squares etc. And Kamsky instantly replied

> **you must be playing a different kind of chess**. white has no plan at all. black just goes... [some moves] and that's it

(of course I might have black and white mixed up above)

It was a striking illustration of how immediate and accurate the evaluation of an elite grandmaster can be. Does anyone remember this at all? I am trying to find the video clip or failing that, the position that the guys were discussing. I am pretty sure it was in the uschesschamps website at the time, but not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I remember this - it was an impressive moment. I don't remember who the players were, but the game was probably from the Open section. Vague recollections of proposed kingside maneuvers for Black, involving ...Qg8-h7 or something likewise extravagant. I don't remember the result of the game or if Kamsky's ideas were played. And unfortunately, most of the videos on the CCSCSL livestream channel from before 2014 seem to be gone.